# url to export excel directly from dataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a dataTable in a html file with some javascript that needs to export an excel file. I am able to export the dataTable data to excel using the option buttons: excelHtml5. It is working fine.

I am wondering if there is a way to create the same excel file (with the dataTable format, style,etc) just calling a url from the browser so the user doesn't need to "preview" the data and click the excel export button to create the excel file.

I am new with dataTable so any help will be appreciate, thanks!